# Filter records not in other query results - SAQL

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I am starting to work with einstein analytics and SAQL and I already searched on internet before posting this question but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I need help to know how can I reference other query results in a filter with SAQL.
Basically I want to filter a dataset of Users by Username that are not in other query results or dataset.

This is what I am trying:

```
q = load "Users";
q = filter q by 'IsActive' == "true";
q = filter q by 'Business_Line_Business__c' == "COV";
q = filter q by 'Username' not in {{ results(all_2)}};
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate unique('Username') as 'unique_Username';
q = limit q 2000;
```

Query "all_2":

```
q = load "LightningPageViewWithUsers";
q = group q by 'User.Username';
q = foreach q generate 'User.Username' as 'Username', count() as 'count';
q = order q by 'Username' asc;
q = limit q 2000;
```

The error I've got is "Binding has not been parsed or has validation errors".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bindings (or Interactions as they are called now) have a very strict syntax, and you don't get very good help on error correction, it usually just crashes. Anyway, here is the documentation: [Bindings documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_bindings.meta/bi_dev_guide_bindings/bi_dbjson_bindings.htm)

Your problem would need something like the following code:

```
 q = filter q by !({{column(all_2.result, ["Username"]).asEquality("Username")}});
```

The .asEquality creates

```
Username in ["XYZ", "YZX", ....]
```

Since you want to exclude these users, you have to surround it with !(...)